# Copying Binary Data

Tags: java

I'm attempting to read a video file, and write it to another file but for some reason when i do an md5sum comparison they differ and the new file is unreadable by VLC. Thoughts?

MD5 sum of original file: b13d9acecd2dd3f869245c8e085f88c2
MD5 sum of new file: d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e

```
public void copyFile() throws IOException {
    BufferedInputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream("/home/zevrant/tmp/test.h264"));
    BufferedOutputStream fileOutputStream = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(new File("/security/footage/test.h264")));
    while(in.available() > 0) {
        bytes = in.readNBytes(in.available());
        fileOutputStream.write(bytes);
        fileOutputStream.flush();
   }
}
```

Comment: First use `ls` to check that the sizes are identical. Then use `cmp` to search for the first byte that differs. Then I would use `dd` + `hexdump` (or `od`) to see the actual difference at that point. BTW, you don't check the return value of your write operation: what if there is not enough space in the destination filesystem?

Comment: Could you use `cp`, or is this the start of a bigger program?

Comment: the end goal is to send a continuous stream over a network connection to a remote server, but this doesn't work if the bytes aren't an exact copy. I don't check the return value because A i know my machine has a good 500GB of space for testing purposes and B that will be a network call instead of a write to local storage once the bytes read in match the original source

Comment: weird after rebooting it's producing an identical file now

Comment: "I don't check the return value..." Please write this down somewhere, so that X years from now when something unexpectedly breaks and you're up to your elbows in legacy code trying to figure out what went wrong, Future You will know who to blame.

Comment: `in.available()` isn't a reliable way to see how many bytes are left.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The fundamental problem with your `copyFile` method is this:

```
   while (in.available() > 0) {
```

It is a problem because `in.available()` returns the number of bytes that can *currently* be read from the input stream *without blocking*.   If the consumer of data "catches up with" the producer, that may be zero bytes, even though you haven't got to the end of the stream yet:

- For a socket, this can happen if the remote server or network are slow, or if there is a "hiccup" in the network.
- For a pipe, this can happen if the program on the other end of the pipe cannot write data fast enough.
- For a regular file (or a file on a file share), this *could* happen file system read-ahead cannot keep enough data in the cache.  (The actual behavior of `available()` for a file depends on the OS and the file system type.  It is unwise to make assumptions ...)

If this happens, you method may incorrectly assume that it has reached the end, and close the streams ... before copying the entire stream.

If you are going to copy a stream "by hand", a correct way to write it is like this:

```
public static void copyFile() throws IOException {
    try (
        InputStream in = new FileInputStream(...));
        OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(new File(...))) {
        byte[] bytes = new byte[8192];   // Or use a larger buffer.
        int nosRead;
        while ((nosRead = in.read(bytes)) > 0) {
            out.write(bytes, 0, nosRead);
        }
    }
}
```

Notes:

1. We don't use `available()` to decide how much to read.  We read up to 8192 byte chunks.  (The number could be bigger, but there are downsides in making the buffer too big.)
2. There is no need to use buffered streams for this.  We are doing our own (simple) buffering.
3. We need to make sure the files are closed.  A *try with resources* is the best way to do this (from Java 7 onward).  The resources (`in` and `out`) will be closed automatically.  (And a close causes a flush.)
4. It is also possible to use `Channel` and `ByteBuffer`, which may be faster.

---

But if you are copying a file to a file, then Java8 `Files.copy(...)` will be simpler and more (probably the most) efficient.  All of the copying is done under the covers, and it is reasonable to assume that it is going to be done optimally (for Java).

With Java 9 you also have the option of using `InputStream.transferTo(...)` which makes use of special I/O syscalls that reduce the memory-to-memory copying when you are transferring data from one "file descriptor" to another.

Answer (score 1):

You are using `in.available()` this can return 0 before reaching the end of the file.

If you wanted to use your loop.

```
byte[] bytes = new byte[1024];

int read;
while ( (read = in.read(bytes)) >= 0) {
    out.write(bytes, 0, read);
}
```

When in is closed or exhausted, `.read` it will return -1.

You could use some of the newer methods though.

```
in.transferTo(out);
```

Or just go with the [Files](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/nio/file/Files.html) option.

```
Files.copy(Paths.get("/home/zevrant/tmp/test.h264"), out );
```

Answer (score 1):

The answer from @Stephen.C is fine. Just the code for normal copying:

```
public void copyFile() throws IOException {
    Path sourcePath = Paths.get("/home/zevrant/tmp/test.h264");
    Path targetPath = Paths.get("/security/footage/test.h264");
    Files.copy(sourcePath, targetPath);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, to read a file as a bytes, you follow these options:-

1- you can read it byte by byte.

```java
int nextByte;
while ((nextByte = in.read()) != -1) {
    out.write(nextByte);
}

out.flush();
```

2- you can declare a byte array with specific size (for example 64) to read bytes.

```java
int nOfReadBytes;
byte[] bytes = new byte[64];
while ((nOfReadBytes = in.read(bytes)) != -1) {
    out.write(bytes, 0, nOfReadBytes);
}

out.flush();
```

3- Another easy and guaranteed solution, you can use `java.nio.file` classes for copying, creating and deleting files or directories. Ex:-

```java
Path originalFile = Paths.get("/home/zevrant/tmp/test.h264");
Path newFile = Paths.get("/security/footage/test.h264");
Files.copy(originalFile, newFile);
```

**The below code is for checking sum purpose only**
If you want to check sum for a file, you can use `DigestInputStream` with `MessageDigest` classes from `java.security` package. Ex:-

```java
public class Hash {
    public static String getHash(File file, String algorithm) {
        String result = "";
    
        try {
            MessageDigest digest = MessageDigest.getInstance(algorithm);
            DigestInputStream inputStream = new DigestInputStream(new FileInputStream(file), digest);
            while (inputStream.read() != -1);
            result = toHexString(digest.digest());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.err.println(e.getMessage());
        }
    
        return result;
    }
    
    private static String toHexString(byte[] bytes) {
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    
        for (byte b : bytes) {
            builder.append(String.format("%02x", b));
        }
    
        return builder.toString();
    }
    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you need to use the read() method instead of the available() method for the InputStream and check if read() returns -1 (like this [example](https://coderfoobar.com/what-is-a-java-inputstream/)). The available() method only returns the amount of data **currently available to be read** and not the size of the entire stream. If the underlying inputstream is from the network (e.g. sockets), then available() can return 0 even when there is no data readily left.